# PHP Getting JSON Data

Tags: php, json, object, web, resources

I have had much success before but I cant seem to get this peice of JSON data from a web resource,

im trying to get the 'rate' : in USD first entry on the page. but it keeps failing, Im obviously doing something wrong, would be greatful if someone could help.

```
    <?php 
    $json = file_get_contents("https://bitpay.com/api/rates");
    $obj = json_decode($json);
    print $obj->{'rate');
    ?>
```

Thanks for any help

Comment: Use `print_r($obj)` to see the actual structure.

Comment: You have no idea what you are doing. Open the URL in your browser. Look at how it is formatted. Then decode the JSON and look at how the data is structured (using `var_dump()` or `print_r()`). Then access the data properly.

Comment: Sorry, Im new to PHP, just trying to learn :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php
function usd_rate(){
$json = file_get_contents("https://bitpay.com/api/rates");
    $obj = json_decode($json);
        foreach($obj as $o){
                if($o->code == 'USD') return $o->rate;
        }
}

echo usd_rate() . "\n";
```